# How can I correct this SQL query?

Tags: sql, db2

I am using a DB2 table. Each Customer has **multiple** fund balances stored in a column "Balance" and a column "As_of_date" to keep track of the date they've had that balance amount since. I need to return all customers that have had an aggregated balance of more than 1 million for the past 90 days.

I can't figure out how to do it. I am new in SQL

```
select Customer from MyTable
where As_of_date >= (current_date - 90 DAYS)
HAVING SUM(Balance) >= '1000000.00'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  What is "aggregated balance"?

Comment: Does it make sense to add up someone's balance snapshots? If I have a balance of 7000 in July and 8000 in August, it doesn't make sense to say I have 15,000. What if I snapshot by week? July 1st 7000. July 8th 7000, July 15th 6000, July 22nd 8000, July 29th 7000. The sum is 35,000 but I don't have any more money than before. Perhaps you want an average balance?

Answer (score 1):

~It's not clear what database engine this is~ (oops: says v clearly DB2!) , or why there's capitals everywhere, but here is the answer in sql pseudocode, more or less:

```sql
select Customer, sum(Balance) as CustomerBalance
from Mytable
where As_of_date >= (current_date - 90 DAYS)
group by Customer
having CustomerBalance > 1000000
```

explanation:

- we want to select all the customers and all their balances,
- but we first filter out anything older than 90 days (the `where as_of_date ...` clause)
- the `group by` breaks down the data by customer, so for each customer, we take all their balances (for the last 90 days) and return a single value for each customer (the sum)
- then finally the `having` clause discards any rows of <Customer, CustomerBalance> that don't exceed a million.

Comment: An explanation would make it a better answer. The `where` clause filters individual rows, but `having` filters thee groups defined by the `group by`. Note that DB2 will not accept a column alias in `having`.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for pointing that out. I tried to put an explanation in addition to yours.

Comment: DB2 is not liking the alias CustomerBalance

Comment: Yeah well all the names are bizarre. Have no idea what kind of database the poster is using; reckoned if I just stuck to their strange conventions they decrypt back into whatever makes sense in their universe lol...

Comment: @HelloQuantumWorld OMG! lol... having 40 browser tabs open explains my mental state right now. I clearly have no reading comprehension left to speak of!

Comment: haha ! no problem, I appreciate your time anyway :)